# Properly pass JDK argument into Maven pom file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, pom.xml

Because I need to customize Host header in HTTP request, I need to start my Spring Boot Java app with following argument (available since JDK 12):

`java -jar -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host application.jar`

but how to pass it into maven pom.xml file to be able to use this argument durring tests which are failing because of missing this flag?

I tried to use maven-compiler-plugin in following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but it's wrong:

> error: invalid flag: -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host

Following examples are not working either:

> -jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host
>
> jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host

So i tried even with spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>-Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host</jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but it's also not working because in that case this flag is ignored and I got restriction error when I run mvn test. Which is not happening when I run java with this flag.

Comment: Can you try with with <jvmArguments>java -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host</jvmArguments> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be configuring the wrong plugin. You said you need to "be able to use this argument during tests" which means you should be configuring [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin).

Have a look at [the example they have provided](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html). May be you can use `systemProperties`:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>propertyName</name>
              <value>propertyValue</value>
            </property>
            [...]
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

or the `argLine` approach:

```xml
<argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=...</argLine>
```